# asp.net out of proc session state when is it restored?

Tags: asp.net, session

We are using Session to save user specific information between requests and are now in the process of converting to an out of proc state server for load balancing. My problem is I do a lot of one time setup for each unique user in Session Start.  With out of proc session state Session Start does not get fired for an existing user.  For example if the web server gets cycled the app receives a BeginRequest but no SessionStart, however I still need to do some configuration with the newly restored session so need a way to know when it has been restored and can be accessed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here [Session State Not Available In This Context - In Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316252/session-state-not-available-in-this-context-in-global-asax)

Application_AcquireRequestState()

Sorry for the question, should have read more carefully.